# How to use an index in a path in Ember

Tags: path, ember.js

I'm trying to bind a textfield to an value in object like this:

```html
{{#each type in controller.currentTypes}}
  <label>
    {{type.name}}
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="controller.contextRemarks[type.id]"}}
  </label>
{{/each}}
```

`controller.currentTypes` and `controller.contextRemarks` are only related in a loose one-to-many manner.

```js
currentTypes = [{id: 1, name: 'Type name 1'}]
```

I don't know if I'm implementing an anti-pattern, but I don't think I can do without the dynamic index and Ember doesn't seem to allow me to use an index in a path.

I tried to solve this using an extra view or a helper, but keep getting stuck.
Is there an ember-ry solution for this?

Comment: It would help to see a jsfiddle. From your example I cannot tell exactly what you are trying accomplish. Also, if ``type`` is related to contextRemarks then type should belongTo/hasOne contextRemark.

Comment: With the relation statement I meant to say that I cannot store extra information in controller.currentTypes

Answer (score 0):

So I worked around this problem by adding a computed property on the controller and storing the generated array in a private property:

```js
App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  remarks: function() {
    var remarks = this.get('currentTypes') || [];
      this._remarks = remarks.map(function(remark) {
        return {
          id: remark.id,
          name: remark.name,
          value: ''
        };
      });

      return this._remarks;
    }.property('currentTypes')
  });
}
```

The view now looks like this:

```html
{{#each remarks}}
  <label>
    {{name}}
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="value"}}
  </label>
{{/each}}
```

Now I can access _remarks to find the user's input, this is the most ember like solution I can come up with and might be the "right solution. ;)